# Space complexity of algorithm to copy a list into a HashSet

Tags: algorithm, hashset

What is the space complexity for an algorithm which places each element from a list into a HashSet? Is it O(n), where n is the size of the list or is it O(k), where k is the number of unique elements in the list. Since the HashSet only grows when we add unique elements to it it seems to me that the latter is correct.

Comment: and what is a *hashset*?

Comment: It's both: O(n+k).  Since K is usually set based on the expected maximum value for N, it's not necessarily constant.

Comment: @RBarryYoung If we do not know the distribution of the values within the list how can we obtain an expected maximum value? Also, why would this be n + k, when k is strictly less that or equal to n? In this case shouldn't the complexity reduce to O(n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space complexity of any algorithm takes into account the size of the input. It is a measure of the maximum working memory that will be needed during the execution of the algorithm. So for **O(n)** size input the space complexity has to be at least **O(n)**. [Source](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/311/html/space-complexity.html)

So given the algorithm used O(n) just for the input, and it isn't a really bad implementation i.e. it uses constant amount of space as it iterates over the list and we know that k < n, so input size will always be the dominating factor in space complexity. So overall the space complexity will be **O(n)**.

Comment: I am sure that for many languages the size of the input does not count against the space complexity. For example, in Java we pass in objects by reference so even if a list contains a billion items all we need in our algorithm is the reference into the list. If we do not need to make a copy of our list then our space complexity could be as low as O(1). For example, consider summing the values in an array. It is very easy to do that in O(1) space in Java.

Comment: In the source you referenced the space complexity could be reduced to O(1) if they had passed pointers to the arrays instead.

Comment: In my previous comments I believe I had mistakenly conflated the ideas of Space Complexity and Auxiliary Space. When I posed the question I had actually meant to ask about the auxiliary space, so as I asked it the answer you gave is correct.